# Can we store sensitive client information with the admins without them(admins) identifying it?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, salt

I am trying to design a pairing application for my university this valentine.  How is it supposed to work, you ask?? The clients will submit preferences to the server and after some days if any two clients have the same preferences, they will be notified -- `not` in any other case. A fool-proof framework design needs to be built for this purpose. What I am willing to do is to ensure my clients that even though they will be submitting their favourite responses to me via my website, I will still not be able to see those as if I would, this application will have issues of privacy. I am trying to match the user preferences with each other, they will obviously be encrypted and there is no way I can match any two unless I decrypt them ***at some point in my server locally*** -- assuming the fact that **RSA** encryption mechanism has a very little probability of collision of hashed values and I definitely cannot match them :) . The bottleneck here then is >> ***never ever decrypt the client preferences locally on the admin's machine/server***. One approach which is currently on my mind is to introduce a `salt` while encrypting which will stay safe in the hands of the client, but still decryption needs to be done at some point in time to match these hashes. Can there be some alternative approach for this type of design, I think I might be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn things around. Design a mailbox-like system and use pseudonyms. Instead of getting an email once a match has been found, make people request it. That way you can leave the preferences unencrypted. Just the actual user has to be hidden from public. Start with an initial population of fake users to hide your early adaptors and you will be done.

I.e.: In order to post preferences, I'll leave a public key to contact me. The server searches matches and posts encrypted messages to a public site. Everyone can see these messages (or not, if you design properly) but I am the only one that can read them.

Comment: `Start with an initial population of fake users to hide your early adaptors` >> Can you please elaborate a little on this?

Comment: How can a user know other user from the pseudonym? There is no way we can leave the preferences unencrypted then

Comment: They _ask_ each other. Once a match has been found it is up to the clients to exchange there contact data.